# How do you make sure only one output is used even if the criteria are met for two outputs?

Tags: java, eclipse

I was working on a little project, nothing crazy just a little thing to show my friends, and I had an issue when I tried to create two different oppourtunities. I was trying to make it so that if the number grenerator came up with the number 1, a different method would be followed than if it came up with a different number. However when I tried it, both methods ran. I was hoping that there was a different way i could try it. Let me know if you have any insights.

I have checked in my java books that are teaching me and online in "Stackoverflow" and in general searches.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random myRandom = new Random();
    long randomNumber;

    System.out.println("What is your question my puppet?");
    keyboard.nextLine();

    randomNumber = myRandom.nextInt(10);

    if (randomNumber ==1) {
        System.out.println("Try rewordding that, it doesn't sound right");
        keyboard.close();

    }              


    if (randomNumber > 5) {
        System.out.println("Ah, I can sense that yes is the answer you're looking for.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Ah, I can sense that no is the answer you're looking for.");
    }

    keyboard.close();
}
}
```

I expect if the number 1 is chosen that the message "Try rewording that, it doesn't sound right" to come up but since it also follows the criteria for a number lower than 5 that message pops up to.

Comment: Make it apart of an `if, else-if` chain. Also don't close a `Scanner` reading from `System.in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `else` before the second (currently independent) `if`. Like,

```
if (randomNumber == 1) {
    System.out.println("Try rewordding that, it doesn't sound right");
    // keyboard.close(); // not needed you have another close call later.
} else if (randomNumber > 5) {
    // ...
```